# How to display selected Tab Bottom line in android

Tags: android

When i am changing my tab background color ,my selected tab bottom line is not visible .any one help me

my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private Context mContext;

    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "MEN-Clothing", "WOMEN", "KIDS" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        
       // getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);



        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }





        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());


        //tabs[position].setTabTextColor();
    //tab.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColor(mContext, R.color.white);



    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

style.xml

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>




<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
  <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/tabStyle</item>

<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
 <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#029C7A</item>

</style>
<style name="ActionBarTabText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">       
<item name="android:textColor">#CFCFC4</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

#FFFFFF

false
        #029C7A

Comment: use 
        app:tabIndicatorColor="true"

in your xml.

Comment: where i need to use this app:tabIndicatorColor="true" can u plese tell me clearly

Comment: in your xml part, inside tab xml . i think it was R.layout.activity_main 

if not working then show xml code too.

Comment: <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    
    
    

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

Comment: this is view pager , where is Tab . can you just edit your question and paste all the code of activity_main which will really help.
this is not the one which i was talking. i am saying aboutr tab xml.